# what is the equivalent of JMX in the ruby platform?

Tags: ruby, jmx

what is the equivalent of JMX in the ruby platform?

Does anybody know?

Comment: I would tell you, if you would tell me what JMX is. And more importantly what you want to do with it. And what the problem you are trying to solve is.

Comment: @Jörg I didn't realize we were requiring new users to post definitions for each technology they reference in their question which *you* aren't familiar with. If you don't know anything about a technology mentioned in a question, google it or don't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

based on your use of the word "equivalent" I'd imagine you're referring to a JMX system for ruby vm/interpreter, and I don't believe there is any such thing.

However if you use JRuby , you can use ruby to use JMX for a Java VM. see ruby gem jmx4r.

Also, http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/06/jmx4r-jruby

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://rubygems.org/gems/jmx

Sorry, its a late reply though.